# Play animation from a specific keyframes in SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I have imported a 3D dinosaur in my app. It has some animations, first, it is idle for 8 seconds and then roars.

I need to repeat this 8 seconds for a while and then continue the rest of animation, and repeat this process. Is there any possible way to repeat an animation from a keyframe or a duration ? for example `00:00` to `00:08` (for 30 seconds), and then continue roar animation?

[image]

Comment: Did you find answer to that?

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde No!